# String Enum Type in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

Is it possible to define enum-like type for string? I know about enums but don't want to use enums in this case, I want to use it as if it's just a string.

```
type Blog = object
  text:     string
  priority: "low" | "normal" | "high"

echo Blog(text: "something...", priority: "high")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enums can have a string value attached to it. A converter could be used for automatic parsing of string to enum. Example ([playground](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2xQn)):

```
import strutils  # for parseEnum

type
  Priority = enum
    pLow = "low", pNormal = "normal", pHigh = "high"
  Blog = object
    text:     string
    priority: Priority

converter toPriority(s: string): Priority = parseEnum[Priority](s)

echo Blog(text: "something...", priority: "high")
#note that parseEnum is style insensitive
echo Blog(text: "something...", priority: "LOW")
try:
  echo Blog(text: "something...", priority: "medium")
except:
  echo getCurrentExceptionMsg()
```

output:

```
(text: "something...", priority: high)
(text: "something...", priority: low)
invalid enum value: medium
```

type definition and converter could probably be automated in a macro such as:

```
stringEnum:
  Priority = ["low", "medium", high"]
```

Implementation of macro left as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem, didn't knew about that feature!

Comment: A warning though: as far as I understand, enums in nim are actually only stored as ordinals and their string representation can only be used for prinitng. In this example, the opposite is done which works, but you cannot send Priority.pLow to a proc that expects a string which is why the converter here is needed, but kind of defeats the purpose of an enum...